# How Can I remove all details from TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Assertions (NUnit.Framework)?

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I want to empty/ remove all details packed in 'TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Assertions'.

How can I do the same ? Pls. guide.

Comment: In TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Assertions , I want to clear details based on some conditions  and want to Pass my test. 
Other way I want is to override the 'SwTestBase.CurrentTest.Result' to Passed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this test should pass with last 2 lines.

```
    try
    {
        Assert.True(1 == 2);
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    var context = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext;
    context.CurrentResult = context.CurrentTest.MakeTestResult();
```